ClosedXML debugging System.OutOfRangeException (maximum allowed length of the value is 255 characters) when loading an XlWorkbook
I'm getting a the below error when trying to load an xlworkbook:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'The maximum allowed length of the value is 255 characters. (Parameter 'value')'
The code is erroring on the following line:
IXLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook("Workbook.xlsm")

The spreadsheet I'm attempting to read in is fairly large, I understand there must be a cell which contains more than the permitted 255 character value limit. However, I can't find any information in the error which would help me ascertain which cell is causing the issue and manually finding the cell would be very difficult (given the size of the spreadsheet).
Is there anyway I can get some more info on which cell is causing the issue?

Solved - the issue was due to a cell with data validation in which the list of permissible values was greater than 255 characters.
